# server side validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation, page-lifecycle

I want to know if I apply server side validation on a text box then when the validation event fires (I means in which state of page cycle this validation has been done in server side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

> Postback event handling: If the
>   request is a postback, control event
>   handlers are called. After that, the
>   Validate method of all validator
>   controls is called, which sets the
>   IsValid property of individual
>   validator controls and of the page.

Answer (score 3):

It fires after the Load phase, before a button-click happens.

But in such a button-click handler, you need to check the results using `Page.IsValid`, to prevent handling the click when there is invalid input.